# How to Calculate Next N-Year-versarry in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I found this tutorial on [calculating the next anniversary date on ExcelJet](https://exceljet.net/formula/next-anniversary-date).

How do I modify this to calculate the next multi-year-versarry.  For example, I have date items that don't occur, but every 3, 5, 8, or 10 years.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the item occurs every multi-years that starts from the "Date", I think it needs to add conditions.

For example, the multi-years is **3**, you may try the following formula.
`=IF(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),3)=0,EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+3)*12),EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+3-(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),3)))*12))`

[image]

For other multi-years, you may replace "3" in formula with the multi-years number.

5 years: `=IF(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),5)=0,EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+5)*12),EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+5-(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),5)))*12))`

8 years: `=IF(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),8)=0,EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+8)*12),EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+8-(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),8)))*12))`

10 yeras: `=IF(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),10)=0,EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+10)*12),EDATE(A2,(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y")+10-(MOD(DATEDIF(A2,B2,"y"),10)))*12))`

[image]

Comment: This is close. (I'm using 5-year as a sanity-check because the head-math is easy.) However, the next 5-year-versarry from March 14, 1975, since March this year is already past, would be in 2025.

Answer (score 1):

The `+1` in the formula add one year. To get the other dates as mentioned on the question, you change `+1` to `+3`, `+5`, `+8` and `+10`.

The formulae for the 1, 3, 5, 8 and 10 years will be:

```
=LET(x,DATEDIF($A6,TODAY(),"y"),EDATE($A6,(x+1)*12))
=LET(x,DATEDIF($A6,TODAY(),"y"),IF(MOD(x,3)=0,EDATE($A6,(x+3)*12),EDATE($A6,(x+3-MOD(x,3))*12)))
=LET(x,DATEDIF($A6,TODAY(),"y"),IF(MOD(x,5)=0,EDATE($A6,(x+5)*12),EDATE($A6,(x+5-MOD(x,5))*12)))
=LET(x,DATEDIF($A6,TODAY(),"y"),IF(MOD(x,8)=0,EDATE($A6,(x+8)*12),EDATE($A6,(x+3-MOD(x,8))*12)))
=LET(x,DATEDIF($A6,TODAY(),"y"),IF(MOD(x,10)=0,EDATE($A6,(x+10)*12),EDATE($A6,(x+10-MOD(x,10))*12)))
```

Based on the example from the image on the OP and the comments to considered "As of" column as today, below are the respective dates:

[image: Results Next N-Year-versarry in Excel]

Comment: I think your formula need correction,, since this you need to re enter for every column ,,, `+3 ` makes it hard code !!

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this. The next 5-year-versarry from 1975 will not be 2022, but 2025.

Comment: @JimFell Please explain why 2025 not 2022 as the stating date "As of" is 2017?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio The starting (i.e. earlier) date is the Date column.  The "As of" column can be thought of as "today()."  5-year increments from 1975 will be 1980, 1985, ..., 2020, 2025, and so on.  If the dates in the "As of" column change sufficiently, it should push the next N-versarry date out another iteration.

Comment: @JimFell See formulas' edit.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This looks better.  (I'm using 5-year as a sanity-check because the head-math is easy.)  However, the next 5-year-versarry from March 14, 1975, since March this year is already past, would be in 2025.

Comment: @JimFell See edit.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio This looks pretty good.  It may be a few days, before I get back to this project, but I'll be sure to update on how it works. ;)

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest a dynamic formula, solves the issue:*

[image]

- Formula in cell J63:

  `=EDATE($H63,(DATEDIF($H63,$I63,"y")+VALUE(LEFT(J$62,2)))*12)`

---

**::Edited::**

*Let me explain that how the formula works:*

- Just break the formula & first take `=DATEDIF(H63,I63,"y")` returns `42`.
- Now take `=VALUE(LEFT(J$62,2))` returns `1`.
- Now combine both.

`=(DATEDIF($H63,$I63,"y")+VALUE(LEFT(J$62,2)))*12` ,,

returns `516`, are **Month** since the results in multiplied by `12`,, `(42+1)*12`.

- Now do this `=EDATE(H63,516)`,, returns `14-03-2018`.
- You may cross check this by adding `516`  months to the date in cell
  H63:

  `=DATE(YEAR(H63),MONTH(H63)+516,DAY(H63))`
- Or you may try this:

  ```
   =DATE(YEAR(H63),MONTH(H63)+(DATEDIF($H63,$I63,"y")+VALUE(LEFT(J$62,2)))*12,DAY(H63))
  ```

*You get `14-03-2018` in cell J63 & so next*.

---

**N.B.**

- In above formula `VALUE(LEFT(J$62,2)))` splits the **number of years** from text are 1, 3, 5, 8 & 10 as number, and makes the formula dynamic rather then hard code.
- Other wise you have to modify the formula for every year like one in J63 should,,
  `=EDATE($H63,(DATEDIF($H63,$I63,"y")+3)*12)`.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this. The next 5-year-versarry from 1975 will not be 2022, but 2025.

Comment: Could you please explain why the next 5-year-versarry from 1975 will be 2022 instead of 2020?

Comment: Hi @JimFell,,, check the Edited part of my post ,, I've explained that how the formula works!!

Comment: Hi @Emily,,  now check the Edited part of my post ,, I've explained that how the formula works!!

Comment: Write your concern if any,,  that why this has been down voted,, help me to improve,, plzz avoid baseless voting !!